# Using k Nearest Neighbour & Dynamic Time Warping for keyword spotting

Tags: speech-recognition, mfcc, reference-request, reference-implementation

As stated in the title, I am currently researching a method using k-NN, specifically, as either an alternative or as a supplement to the DTW algorithm in keyword spotting based on MFCC. I have read through various answers on this forum (mainly [Speech recognition using MFCC and DTW(Dynamic Time Warping)?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29165/speech-recognition-using-mfcc-and-dtwdynamic-time-warping)) and I would like to know if anyone could direct me to somewhere I can find more research or implementations which employ the k-NN.

Comment: If you find any of the answers useful, please mark it as accepted, so that question is answered and can help other people.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the k-NN in conjunction with DTW, then it's quite easy. Assuming that you have the speech corpora of keywords you should do the following at the training stage:

- Each keyword should have more than one utterance recorded
- Extract the MFCC's for all the recordings and store them - these are effectively your "model data" - training samples.

Classification consists of:

- Extract the matrix of MFCC's for the test sample
- Calculate the DTW of the test sample with each and every MFCC matrix that was extracted and the training stage.
- Store the final distance for each comparison. Now you should have a vector of total DTW distances (of a length equal to the number of the training examples):

  - *test vs. class1_sample1*: 10.2
  - *test vs. class1_sample2*: 20.3
  - *test vs. class1_sample3*: 15.1
  - *test vs. class2_sample1*: 3.1
  - *test vs. class2_sample2*: 2.5
  - ...
- For each of the classes (keywords), sort the distances (from small to large)
- Pick the *k* top distances for each class and average them. These are the per-class memberships.
- Predict the keyword by choosing the class with smallest distance.

Answer (score 0):

You say " I would like to know if anyone could direct me to somewhere I can find more research or implementations which employ the k-NN"

k-NN with DTW is used in many 100s of papers. Many of them cite [a], so if you search for papers that cite [a]..

In addition, the most cited (and award winning!) paper on k-NN with DTW in the last decade is [b], which has many examples (and nice videos).

[a] http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/time_series_data/
[b] http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/UCRsuite.html