# How to compare 2 MFCC (compare them if they where created from same speaker)

Tags: speech-processing, speech-recognition, mfcc, voice

- There are multiple speakers.
- Each speaker generates multiple MFCC.
- If I'm getting two different MFCC, can we know if those MFCC came from 2 different speakers or same speaker ?

How can we compare them and check this ?

Comment: A naive approach:
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/40830/8202
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/29167/8202

Answer (score -1):

- You can find the distance between the MFCC features for different speakers. The distance should be zero for the same speaker and larger with different speakers.
- You can use different types of distance functions or even similarity functions used generally to compare between probability density functions.
- Also, corresponding to each speaker you should generate a single matrix of MFCC coefficients which is composed of multiple coefficients for each frame. So, the output MFCC should be of dimension: (number of frames, number of coefficients).
- Every speaker's MFCC dimension should be the same to compare them.

Comment: I look on 2 different MFCC matrix of same speaker, and the values are different. so we need more sophisticated way to compare

Comment: Was both of them obtained from the same audio recording?

Comment: Usually, these features change with the words and the way u speak so essentially unless it is the same recording it may not be same.